# Using Delphi XE5 on Android to get HTML response from webserver

Tags: php, html, delphi

Setup on my server is a set of PHP scripts which when run will interface with a MySQL database and return information in the form of a HTML response. I want my android application to be able to 'navigate' to one of these pages and post/get the information required for validation and the query, and then get a response.

I cant find out how to get the HTML response information from a browser or find any other method to do this communication. I cannot connect directly with the SQL database as the php scripts are the interface for an application and website also and I want to connect all platforms through the php scripts.

Does anyone know of a means by which I can communicate with the PHP server and read the response details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi ships with [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) preinstalled.  Indy works on mobile platforms, including Android.  You can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component to send HTTP `GET` and `POST` requests to your webserver as needed.  Response data can be given to you as either a  `String` (which `TIdHTTP` will decode to UTF-16 for you) or a `TStream` (raw data).